# Are O(n+m) and O(n) notations equivalent if m<n?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, rabin-karp

I am reading about the [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) algorithm on Wikipedia and the time complexity mentioned in there is O(n+m). Now, from my understanding, m is necessarily between 0 and n, so in the best case the complexity is O(n) and in the worst case it is also O(2n)=O(n), so why isn't it just O(n)?

Comment: I think this is just to show that there is linear dependency also between complexity of algorithm and `m`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, Robin-Karp expresses it's asymptotic notation as `O(m+n)` as a means to express the fact that it takes linear time relative to `m+n` and not just `n`. Essentially, the variables, `m` and `n`, have to mean something whenever you use asymptotic notation. For the case of the Robin-Karp algorithm, `n` represents the length of the text, and `m` represents the combined length of both the text and the pattern. Note that `O(2n)` means the same thing as `O(n)`, because `O(2n)` is still a linear function of *just* `n`. However, in the case of Robin-Karp, `m+n` isn't really a function of *just* `n`. Rather, it's a function of both `m` and `n`, which are two independent variables. As such, `O(m+n)` doesn't mean the same thing as `O(n)` in the same way that `O(2n)` equates to `O(n)`.

I hope that makes sense. :-P

Answer (score 0):

`m` and `n` measure different dimensions of the input data. Text of length `n` and patterns of length `m` is not the same as text of length `2n` and patterns of length `0`.

`O(m+n)` tells us that the complexity is proportional to both the length of the text and the length of the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

There are some scenarios where saying complexity in form of `O(n+m)` is suitable than just saying `O(max(m,n))`.

**Scenario**:

Consider **BFS**(Breadth First Search) or **DFS**(Depth First Search) as Scenario.
It will be more intuitive and will convey more information to say that the complexity is `O(E+V)` than `max{E,V}`. The former is in Sync with actual algorithmic description.